# displaying a loader while initializing a jQuery image slider

Tags: jquery, image, slider, loader

Hi I've built a large image gallery using [this wonderful jQuery slider](http://bqworks.com/products/advanced-slider/responsive.html), and given the number of slides I'm including, the initial load time is significant, and I'm wondering if there's a simple way for me to integrate a basic loading animation div--eg. spinner with "loading gallery.." text-- that is hidden once the slider has fully loaded? I'm curious if there's a way for me to direct the DOM to first display the loading div, and perhaps use one of the slider's callback functions-- or via jQuery(?)-- to pull out the div when fully initialized? Ultimately, I'm hoping to display something to the user for the 5-10 seconds that the scripts, markup and thumbnails are loaded into the browser (I am using a lazy-loading feature, so it's at least not initially loading all the full-size images.)

Thanks for any insight here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as below but keep in mind its not tested.

**js**

```
$(window).load(function(){
   // initialize slider.
   // remove loading_image image as below
   $('img#loading_image').remove();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div><img src="loading.jpg" alt="" id="loading_image" /></div>
<div><img src="image.jpg" class="hide" alt="" /></div>
<div><img src="image.jpg" class="hide" alt="" /></div>
<div><img src="image.jpg" class="hide" alt="" /></div>
<div><img src="image.jpg" class="hide" alt="" /></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#loading_image { display: block; other css code. }
.hide { display: none; }
```

Hope this will help what this code does is until page is fully loaded it will hide all the slider images except loading image and once page is fully loaded with all images it will work as you need.

Comment: thanks Dipesh, this is an interesting approach. I'm wondering, in line with your suggestion, if I just created an absolutely positioned div with the loading image and placed it just under the opening <body> tag and then removed the element as you specify after the initialization of the slider, would that work in effectively the same manner? also, I'm assuming functions in $(window).load or $(document).ready are executed in the order they're listed?

Comment: yeah it work fine but i prefer you to add loading image inside slider image container..and and document raedy will call when document is ready and window.load run when page is loaded..i mean The ready event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded, while the onload event occurs later, when all content (e.g. images) also has been loaded. Also Note that the ready event is an extension defined by jQuery, where onload is built-in